# import excel to ms-sql format hh:mm incorrect

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a excel table that has a time column I have format that column in my excel to custom hh:mm , and i'm importing that table to Ms-sql using the import data tool in 2014 management studio , how ever the data i'm getting is type DataTime and instead if getting (like 16:10 ) I'm getting 1899-12-30 16:10:00.000
how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, a date is stored as the number of days since the epoch (1900-01-01 in Windows); the time is the fractional part.

So a column in Excel with just a time will always have a year when imported to SQL.

It is not possible with the SQL Server import tool to convert an Excel time column to an SQL *time* column, so you will either need to use SSIS to import the file or convert the data type in SQL with `CONVERT(time(0), mycolumn)`.